# Salesforce Community Guest User Profile license assignment 1st org) 'Guest' AND 2nd org) 'Guest User License'?

Tags: lightning-community

[image]
1st org. now license assigned is 'Guest' user license.

[image]
2nd org. now license assigned is 'Guest User License' user license.

Can we edit the license for this profile? If yes, how?
Or can we control assignment of license to guest user profile for communities guest user.